# Renaming downloaded webpages from Chrome without affecting styling, images, etc

Tags: google-chrome, website

When I download a webpage with Chrome I am given an HTML file and a folder of files associated with the webpage, which includes styling, images, etc. When I rename the HTML file, the webpage no longer works with styling and images gone. This happens even if I rename the corresponding folder with the exact same name. How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the downloaded HTML file. It contains "hardcoded" paths to resources in the associated directory. If the directory is renamed, these paths have to be updated accordingly.

HTML files are text files. The *Find and replace* feature in any competent text editor should do the trick. (Notepad isn't necessarily a *competent* text editor.)